# Exporting structs in go

Tags: go, struct, export

I have a file that has a few structs in it:

```
type StructBase struct {
       // ... lots of fields
}

type Struct1 struct {
       StructBase
       // ... lots of fields
}

ImplementedStruct1 := &Struct1{
      name: "test",
      // ...
}
```

I understand in Go that all capital letter variable names are exported from the package. So naturally `ImplementedStruct1` is exported. However, for whatever reason I am getting an

`ImplementedStruct1 unexpected`.

Am I missing something here that will allow me to export an implemented struct object from this package? This code seems consistent with [this](https://gobyexample.com/structs) tutorial on Go structs. I apologize if this is obvious, I have been searching and am still pretty new to Go. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use [short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) in the package scope. You will have to declare your variable with the following syntax:

```
var ImplementedStruct1 = &Struct1{
      name: "test",
      // ...
}
```